# java library for zip64

Tags: java, zip

What is currently the best library to do zip64 with in Java? I need to zip and unzip files / directories larger than 4 GB.

I read that Java 7 has support for zip64. But I guess if I develop for Java 7 this only works if all the computers on which the application will be installed have Java 7 JRE? Is this correct?

At the moment I am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/zip64file/ . But here I was wondering if this is still the best choice? I would like to have a library that supports zipping of directories out of the box. Now I have to do the traversing of the directory structure myself.

Comment: "if I develop for Java 7 this only works if all the computers on which the application will be installed have Java 7 JRE? Is this correct?" Yupp, that is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Also [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html) supports Zip64 format.

Comment: If you can use Tar then Apache Commons has API for creating Tar and they do support creating archives for files more than 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like TrueZIP 6.7 Beta has the features you need http://cworld.wikidot.com/development:open-source-java-zip64-library-truezip

- enables client applications to access ZIP archive transparently as if they were just directories in a file's path name
- New in TrueZIP 6.7 Beta: The low level ZIP API now supports ZIP64 extensions
- Runs on J2RE 1.4.2 or higher