# Java - open zip file with more than 65535 files inside

Tags: java, android, zip

I am facing interesting problem. I have in my ZIP archive more than 65535 files inside my archive and that is problem, because standard ZIP archive can carry no more then 65535 to be able to successfully unpack them. Have you faced same problem? I am currently unzipping in Android (using ZipEntry), so is there any way how to increase numbers of files I can store in one ZIP?

Thanks

Comment: If you are the producer of the zip you might want to split it into several zip archives when generating the file.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an one and only solution. Inporting another ZIP libraries is unsuccessfull in Android

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [zip](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/259)
It looks like its a limitation of zip format.

There is another thread in this wonderful site that you may be interested to read:
[zip64 library in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601970/java-library-for-zip64)
I have no idea how does it ports to Android though...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: [Java's built-in java.util.zip does support ZIP64 from version Java 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#ZIP64).
As far as I know, the Android SDK was designed for java5/6, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android).
But you might be able to extract the classes from java.util.zip and make use of those in your project.